# yii : Trying to get property of non-object in isAdmin()

Tags: php, yii

I am following a tutorial from this site : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/459/integrating-hybridauth-directly-into-yii-without-an-extension/

After returning from google it shows the following error

> PHP notice
>
> Trying to get property of non-object
>
> /home/jrickby/public_html/mobisite.website/admin/models/mainsite_models/WebUser.php(39)

```
 public function isAdmin()
 {
     //return false;
     $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);

     return intval($user->is_admin) == 1; // error is here 
 }
```

Please help me solve this problem

I followed only what is mentioned in the tutorial I have not added any extra code. I removed `$haComp->processLogin()` from `actionLogin()` because it has throwing some errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you need to check

1. Check user table have field "is_admin".
2. You need to call getUserProfile() function which get user information.
3. loadUser($id) function responding all fields of user table with roles.
4. Always check error empty condition before fetching table field.